# Tensorflow Inception Train and Create GraphDef

Tags: tensorflow

I'm quite new to using Tensorflow. I was playing around the Inception-V3 model for image recognition in this repo:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception#how-to-train-from-scratch

It provides binaries to help you train your own model. However in the Tensorflow docs on Image Recognition,

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition/

They allow you to download and utilize a pre-trained Inception-V3 model trained on ImageNet data. The model that you download, is in the format of a `.pb` GraphDef whereas the model you generate in the `tensorflow/models/inception` repo is a `.ckpt` "checkpoint` formatted file.

What's the difference between these two types of files and how can I convert my generated inception model into a GraphDef file?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation on metagraphs](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/meta_graph) should be helpful. It shows to save and load these structures which contain enough information to reproduce the model.